# Automatically inserted comments don't appear anymore

Tags: bug, status-completed, automatic-comments

Usually when someone flags/votes to close a question as a duplicate, a comment is automatically inserted.

> Does this answer your question? [link to proposed duplicate]

But since this morning those comments don't seem to appear anymore.

I first noticed it on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611551/indexof-but-more-than-1-output) (now deleted) question after I voted to close it as a duplicate. Then on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63611724/how-to-stop-the-loop-for-javascript-scroll-down) again<sup>1</sup>.

I also noticed someone voting to close with a custom reason without any comment appearing. (IIRC on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63612225/probleme-danimation).)

Especially for the custom close reason, I can't imagine that this change was intentional.

(Maybe a moderator can verify if these comments were deleted or were never inserted at all?)

<sup>1. On this one I inserted the comment manually and removed it again after it was closed.</sup>

Comment: I have seen two weird things this morning. I closed a question with a custom comment, but going back into the close menu it said I'd closed as Opinion Based. Just now, someone else closed with a custom comment, and the close menu shows there 1 vote for a "community specific reason", but on the next menu, there are no votes showing at all. Something has definitely broken in close voting.

Comment: Now I'm seeing the dupe comment remain instead of getting deleted ‍♂️ (https://stackoverflow.com/q/63615329/215552, e.g.)

Comment: @HereticMonkey I believe that is the case for a while already. I don't know the specifics, but I've noticed that those are not being deleted if the comment is posted in the name of someone that doesn't have the VTC privilege yet. (So it was caused by a flag instead of a close vote.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

We had a small bad code-push that went onto the servers at 07:54 UTC and was resolved at 09:54 UTC; during this 2 hours interval, some amount of our "side effect" code was effectively disabled. I *believe* that this was a side-effect of this problem.

We have:

1. fixed the affected code (released at 09:54 UTC)
2. added *multiple separate* automated mechanisms to ensure that we can't hit the same problem again
3. started reviewing for any side-effects we missed in this period that will have *significant* impact

We apologise for any adverse impact here.

Comment: This time, it wasn't Nick fault.

Comment: @Braiam to save time, we (genuinely) have a "wheel of blame" that assigns blame randomly, so that we can move past finger-pointing and get on with the more important job of fixing things. However! I have to say: I didn't actually contribute to this particular fire - I got to my desk in the morning, and noticed some sparks, and made the mistake of looking to see what was wrong ...

Comment: I really hope you learned the lesson: do not look at the sparks behind the courtain :D. BTW, I know of the wheel of blame.